# ORACLE SQL table creation

Tags: sql

[SQl table creation showing error, pls look into this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUXPn.png)

Comment: I assume the table dept you try to create a foreign key for does not exists

Comment: yeah, thanks man I got it now, I appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the dept table that the fk is referencing exists.

If so, try creating the table without constraints and add them in after using an ALTER statement.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your referencing a foreign of table Dept which does not exits.

**Please create dept Table first and then create Employee table.**

Comment: thanks, man, it's working now, I appreciate that!